# IdentityDbContext<User> в классе Library | Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь вынести репозиторий для работы с базой данных в отдельное приложение в solution. Создал новое приложение класса библиотеки "Asp.Net Class Library".

Далее установил весь необходимый пакет для работы с базой. Даже более чем нужно установил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-первых интересно почему треугольник на пакетах, если все норм установилось.

Теперь далее о главном.

Перенес модель контекста в это новое приложение

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Models.Models;

namespace Repository
{
    public class ApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext>    options)
         : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

       
    }
}
```

И у меня студия категорически отказывается наследовать этот класс. Модель User подключена из библиотеки классов такой же, где хранятся все модели.

Вот скрин ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?

Comment: замените скриншот исключения на текст

Comment: Вы путаете `Asp.Net Core` c `Asp.Net`. Нельзя в проекте `Asp.Net Core` использовать `Asp.Net Class Library`, а надо использовать `Class Library (.Net Core)` или `.Net Standart`. Так же не следует путать просто `Entity Framework` с `Entity Framework Core`.